# how to have archives for specific categories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a website with wordpress.  I a few menu items/tabs each of which display a part of the blog but that is filtered based on category, so the for each tab the url structure would be:

examplewebsite.com/?category=1
examplewebsite.com/?category=3

based off which tab was selected.  On each page there is a calendar widget which allows me to click on a date to see posts from that specific day.  The calendar sends to a url structure like:

examplewebsite.com/?m=20120415
examplewebsite.com/?m=20120417

however this would show all of the categories based on the date.  I want to set it up such that if I am on this page: examplewebsite.com/?category=1 and I click on the calendar it would add "&?m=20120415" to my current URL that way it would include the filter of the category

I have pretty extensive knowledge with java, but have essentially no knowledge of php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, the wp query_post display post and it does have a parameter for getting post based on categories

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts('cat=1');
//get the post under the category 1

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: any chance you could dumb that down a bit? I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: the loop contains the loop of the post, so if you want to display the post or the list of the post basing on the category you may need to change the_post by changing the query, <?php query_posts('cat=1') ?> contains the posts under the category id 1, so if you loop the posts under it it will just display the posts under the category 1.